# Maven can't find a module

Tags: java, maven

I've been trying for the last few weeks at this point to get Maven to compile my project and I am so desperate

I am running the following maven command on the root directory:

```
mvn clean verify -fae -X
```

And I am getting the following output: [log on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KtcKL2jM)

This clearly means that it cannot find the module that it has already identified, during compile (meaning any goal that includes compile will throw the same error). IntelliJ could even find the source of the module (with find usages) in the MAVEN LOCAL REPO as a compiled JAR, which baffles me because maven doesn't seem to want to figure that one out and now after renaming it can find the sources in this project too, so I don't know where it could be going wrong at all.

I can't provide any relevant code, because I have no clue where the issue might lie. All of my code can be found on my [GitHub here](https://github.com/Ieris19/IerisLib/), in the IerisLib repository [on the experimental branch](https://github.com/Ieris19/IerisLib/tree/experimental).

I am extremely frustrated with this issue and at this point I don't know what to do. I have attempted:

Deleting all and cloning again, changing the module's names twice, rewriting the module-info.java files and just playing around with Maven command parameters(that's how I came up with -fae -X instead of just mvn clean verify).

I'm running Maven 3.8.5

Please, any help is appreciated

Comment: You are using the maven-compiler-plugin version 3.1 (which is 9+ years old) and having `/src/main/java/module-info.java:[3,26] module not found: ierislib.utilities` The plugin does not even know about `module-info` nor existed a JDK which supported that... You have to define the version for the maven-compiler-plugin (3.10.1 at the moment) in your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise Is that always the case? As in, do I always have to define the plugins and their versions in my POM? I was using up until now the defaults bundled with IntelliJ, and my parent POM file includes some plugins in an attempt to update them. I recently gave up on the issue, but will try and see if it works now

Comment: You should always bind all plugins with its version. That makes sure everytime you build you are using the same versions of plugins even if you change Maven version... best would be having this defined in the parent (corporate) and define them... apart from that you are using a module-info.java ...